# Methode to deploy outlook add in with step by step

Tags: reactjs, outlook, outlook-web-addins

So I created an outlook add-in and I am able to sideload in outlook desktop app for development,
But now I want to deploy in an organisation so they will be able to use it I followed the deployment doc of [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish#:~:text=Outlook%20add%2Din%20deployment,Outlook%202013%20or%20later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish#:%7E:text=Outlook%20add%2Din%20deployment,Outlook%202013%20or%20later)

But I am unable to get how to deploy it I am going around and round reading there documentation.
Can anyone suggest me step or tell me which site to follow for clear vision on deploying outlook add-in or which software to use for deployment. Thank you

Comment: To clarify, do you have manifest and web server ready, and you are just looking to get the addin for users in the organization? The approach can be different depending on the target org and the environment.  For Outlook the main choices (from the link you included) are either Exchange or Centralized Deployment, or AppSource if you plan to make your addin available in store.office.com.

Comment: I have manifest, what do you mean by web server ready, not only in organization but I am planing to deploy for every one

Comment: by web server, I mean where is the code (html/js) for the webapp hosted?  Asking another way, where is the source locations or urls in the manifest pointing to?  For development, it can be local (https://localhost/...). To deploy the addin for others, the addin needs to be on a web location accessible for your target users (This shows 1 way to deploy https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-add-in-vs-code)

Comment: In that case I have web server ready

Comment: Your HTML files need to be moved to your web server, then your manifest modified to point to those files. At that point, the manifest can be sideloaded by anyone to their Exchange Account, and they should be able to access your add-in. If you want to be in the Office Store, you need to submit to AppSource, and go through an approval process.

Comment: For informational purposes, what is unclear about the documentation? Your feedback may be used to improve the documentation.

Comment: thanks we were able to do it using Centralized Deployment,and for Centralized Deployment it is hard to undestand for newbe like me

Answer (score 0):

You need to upload your add-in's manifest to the Exchange admin center, so the add-in will be available for all Exchange users. To assign add-ins to a tenant, you should use the Exchange admin center to upload a manifest, either from a file or a URL, or add an add-in from AppSource.

You may find the following video helpful - [How to Deploy Office Add-ins within Your Organization](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/P574).